# How to update Azure AD MS Group Mail and ProxyAddresses field using PowerShell

Tags: email, entra-id, powershell-v7, microsoft-graph

I need to update email address domain for all Azure AD Groups (of all types Unified, Dynamic ... ) and I am using PowerShell 7 with latest stable AzureAD module.

I have an issue with setting new value to "Mail" and "ProxyAddresses" properties using Set-AzureADMSGroup cmdlet.
Can somebody help / provide information or example on how to correctly set those properties, since documentation is not clear for this. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0

In case this is not possible with this cmdlet, then I need to use Exchange Online Powershell to manage all groups via seperated cmdlet regarding the GroupTypes ?

```
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
Connect-AzureAD

$AzureADMSGroups = Get-AzureADMSGroup -All:$true -Filter "mail ge ' '"

foreach ($AzureADGroup in $AzureADGroups) {
    $newMail = $AzureADGroup.Mail.Replace('olddomain.com','newdomain.com')
    $AzureADGroup | Set-AzureADMSGroup -Replace @(Mail = $newMail } }
}
```

Error which I have is that -Replace parametar is not found.
I also tried:

```
$AzureADGroup.Mail = $newMail
$AzureADGroup | Set-AzureADMSGroup
```

Which does not throw any output or error, but value is not changed in Azure AD.
I also need to update ProxyAddresses field/property in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-AzureADMSGroup cmdlet does not seem to support changing email addresses, according to documentation [here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0)

```
$AzureADGroup.Mail = $newMail
```

It just changes the value of variable.

Try using Exchange Online module

```
     Set-UnifiedGroup
     Set-Group 
     Set-DistributionGroup
     Set-DynamicDistributionGroup
```

etc.

If you tell me exactly what you need, I could help you write it.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear and working. However I wanted to find a way how to use AzureADMSGroup for setting primary email and proxyAddress (Email Addresses).